# Angular splice not working

Tags: angularjs, array-splice

My splice code is not working. I am trying to delete it from Ui on basis of index from array list.

```
$scope.deleteSearchResult=function(index,ruleId){
    var responsePromise = $http.post("ruleSearchDelete/"+ruleId);
    responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(" Rule Deleted Successfully");
        self.ruleDataList.splice(index, 1);
    });
    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("AJAX failed!");
    });

}
```

index & ruleDataList watch values have been shown in image link
https://ibb.co/cbgUav

Data is deleted from database..only splice functionality not working

Comment: It's not an answer to your problem directly - but I useally send the new situation from the back-end onwards to the view after a delete / put / post - instead of manipulating the front-end datasource. What's 1 extra request  of a cost in order to guard the latest data snapshot?

Comment: In image it is showing index value as 6, but last index of the array is 5

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `index` as the parameter is not correct.
 Since you have the `ruleId`, find the index of that object in the array and then splice.

```
$scope.deleteSearchResult=function(ruleId){
    var responsePromise = $http.post("ruleSearchDelete/"+ruleId);
    responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        for(var i=0; i < self.ruleDataList.length - 1; i++) {
            if(self.ruleDataList[i][23] == ruleId) {
                self.ruleDataList.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        //var index = self.ruleDataList.findIndex(x => x[23] == ruleId); // Not supported in IE
        //var index =self.ruleDataList.map(x => x[23]).indexOf(ruleId) //Supported everywhere

    });
    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("AJAX failed!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that IE doesn't support `findIndex()`

Comment: Yes, this should work everywhere `var index =self.ruleDataList.map(x => x.ruleId).indexOf(ruleId)`

Comment: You don't have to loop around the array as `findIndex()` already does that in memory. This method will look for the `ruleId` among all the objects of the array that matches the `ruleId` sent as the parameter. so simply, just add the two lines of code from the answer in the success callback.

Comment: Moreover, you shouldn't splice the array after deleting it from the database, rather make a `http` call to re fetch the `ruleDataList` as that would help avoid concurrency issue and well i.e the point of using a single page application.

Comment: in the array ruleId is at index 23

Comment: Is `ruleId` a property of the array or is it a property of the objects in the array?

Comment: @sajal to be specific rule id is not a property 23 is. And yes it is a property of object in array

Comment: @Sajal x => x[23] is giving **Uncaught syntax error:unexpected token =>**

Comment: Your probably have a typo in your code, update to the answer works fine!

Comment: that's a javascript function, nothing to do with angular. You could try with a simple `for loop`. see the update

Comment: Problem fixed...my earlier splice functionality only worked fine...there was a code change due which ruleDataList was not updated. Btw do upvote my question so that people may find your answer helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your splice is working correctly.

The thing is that angular change detection will check if the array he has in memory is the same as the array you have in your controller.

As far as arrays equality is checked by reference, angular will never notice the array has changed.

The thing you can do to copy your updated array to a new reference is using slice after the splice.

```
self.ruleDataList.splice(index, 1).slice(0);
```